# How to trigger remote-api-handler of angucomplete-alt from controller without user input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I am using [angucomplete-alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) in my angularJs project , which works fine when user type in input box . But now I want to add voice recognition in it , so when I get string from my speechToText function , I can set that string to angucomplete-alt with

```
$scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:changeInput', 'ex5', 'voiceInput');
```

but angucomplete-alt doesn't trigger remote-api-handler so I am unable to fetch data .
I have tried with Jquery and dispatchevent keypress as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some hack , angucomplete-alt uses keyup event to recognise change ,aslo add '_value' as id to input , so I use

```
 var el = document.getElementById('ex5_value');
 el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup'));
```

and angucomplete-alt triggers the remote-api-handler function.